# Laravel chunk returns null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm needing to chunk my query as it's making PHP run out of memory, however the below code just dumps `null`:

```
$chunked = $query->chunk(25, function ($events) {
    //dd($events);
});
dd($chunked);
```

However, when I do the below, it dumps the first chunk of 25:

```
$chunked = $query->chunk(25, function ($events) {
    dd($events);
});
//dd($chunked);
```

No combination of changing `dd($events);` to the likes of `return $events`, `return true`, iterating over each item in each chunk and returning that - works.

Am I stupid/doing something wrong or is this not working like it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chunk()` is a helper method which you can use on an instance of Query Builder or Eloquent Builder. In both cases, the method returns `void`:

- [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_chunk)
- [Eloquent Builder](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_chunk)

This means that your `$chunked` variable will be always empty.

The syntax you need to employ is the following:

**Query Builder**

```
DB::table('users')->chunk(100, function($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        //
    }
});
```

**Eloquent**

```
Flight::chunk(200, function ($flights) {
    foreach ($flights as $flight) {
        //
    }
});
```

Basically, all you need to do is to use a loop within the callback function of `chunk()` to modify your results.

Comment: So I was completely misinterpreting how it works. Thanks.