# Laravel eloquent chunk method return all the time false or null

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel v4.2. I want to delete conversation between two users but Now I want that If one user delete the conversation than other user can view the conversation until second user also delete the conversation.
For this I have two column to delete conversation name "delete_on" and "delete_two". For this purpose I am using eloquent chunk method which always return false or null.

```
$return = Message::where('message_to', '=', $userData['id'])
                    ->where('message_from', '=', $userData['message_from'])
                    ->orwhere(function($query) use($userData) {
                        $query->where('message_to', '=', $userData['message_from'])
                        ->where('message_from', '=', $userData['id']);
                    })->chunk(100,function($messages) use($userData){
                        foreach ($messages as $msg){
                            if(empty($msg->delete_one)){
                                $msg->delete_one = $userData['id'];
                            }else{
                                $msg->delete_two = $userData['id'];
                            }
                            if($msg->save()){
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: what is the sql you are getting here?

Comment: You're calling chunk on `Query` rather then a `Collection`. You need to end the query first (`->get()` or `->paginate()`...).

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid no sql getting

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid after implementing your answer i am receiving following error 
"array_chunk() expects parameter 3 to be boolean, object given"

Comment: yes you are using chunk as query bulider instance but by using `get()` it act as an collection and thus returning the array

Comment: hey did my code worked for you?? Have you tried my code?

Answer (score 0):

To know more about `chunk()` refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489440/laravel-chunk-returns-null/31491656#31491656) mentioned in the comments Thanks Gokigooooks for the acknowledgement.

The syntax you need to employ is the following for in your case it's eloquent:

**Eloquent**

For first of all check whether you are getting chunk result here like this:

```
Message::where('message_to', '=', $userData['id'])
                ->where('message_from', '=', $userData['message_from'])
                ->orwhere(function($query) use($userData) {
                    $query->where('message_to', '=', $userData['message_from'])
                    ->where('message_from', '=', $userData['id']);
                })->chunk(100,function($messages) use($userData){
                    foreach ($messages as $msg){
                        dd($msg); or print_r($msg);
                    }
                });
```

Now try this

```
$return = Message::where('message_to', '=', $userData['id'])
                    ->where('message_from', '=', $userData['message_from'])
                    ->orwhere(function($query) use($userData) {
                        $query->where('message_to', '=', $userData['message_from'])
                        ->where('message_from', '=', $userData['id']);
                    })->chunk(100,function($messages) use($userData){
                        foreach ($messages as $msg){
                            if(empty($msg->delete_one)){
                                $msg->delete_one = $userData['id'];
                            }else{
                                $msg->delete_two = $userData['id'];
                            }
                                $msg->save();
                        }
                    });
```